# Add page content dynamically MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dynamic, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to build a manage environment for my users so they could create new views (to give a title, a category, and the main content) or edit the content of the views that already have been created. I need to store this information in a database and have it appear in my site. I search through the internet but I didn't find a solution. I need this because I would like my site to have searchable content and because I have to many pages. Is that possible to achieve with MVC?

Comment: Are you looking for a CMS? Then you could take a look here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/717523/Top-NET-Based-CMS-Content-Management-System

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. first step

Save view content as string using a wysiwyg editor, I recomend

http://summernote.org/

2. You need show your html using Html.raw() :

Exemple:  `Html.Raw("<div class=\"resource-row\">")`

that way you will show your string as HTML.

I hope it is useful